# Spring boot app, neo4j LoadOneDelegate null - Runs spring boot + IDE not jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-social, neo4j-ogm

I'm building an application that uses Spring boot and neo4j ogm.

When i run it from spring tool suite or from gradle boot run, it works fine. However, after packaging it into a jar I get this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.lookup(LoadOneDelegate.java:56) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar!/:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:49) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar!/:na]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.load(Neo4jSession.java:142) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.0.4.jar!/:na]
at comds.service.GenericService.find(GenericService.java:32) ~[classes!/:na]
at comds.service.UserServiceImpl.find(UserServiceImpl.java:36) ~[classes!/:na]
at comds.service.UserServiceImpl.find(UserServiceImpl.java:25) ~[classes!/:na]
at comds.linkedIn.LinkedInSaveUser.saveUser(LinkedInSaveUser.java:84) ~[classes!/:na]
at comds.controller.LinkedInController.home(LinkedInController.java:64) ~[classes!/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
```

I suspect this is to do with the ogm configuration as the packages are used to define the meta data in ogm, which seems to be null:

```
package comds;

import org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;

public class Neo4jSessionFactory {
private final static String [] packages = {"comds.domain"};

private final static SessionFactory sessionFactory =  new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(),packages);


private static Neo4jSessionFactory factory = new Neo4jSessionFactory();

public static Neo4jSessionFactory getInstance() {
    return factory;
}

private Neo4jSessionFactory() {
}
private static  Configuration getConfiguration() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.driverConfiguration()
    .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver")
    .setURI("http://neo4j:test@localhost:7474");

    return configuration;
}

public Session getNeo4jSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
}
```

For some reason the COMDS user class is not being read:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl extends GenericService<COMDSUser> implements UserService{


@Override
public Class<COMDSUser> getEntityType() {
    return COMDSUser.class;
}

@Override
public COMDSUser find(Long id) {
   COMDSUser user = super.find(id);
   if(user != null){
   return applyPrivacySettings(user);
   }
   return null;
}
//... more stuff 

public class COMDSUser extends COMDSEntity{
public enum privacySettings{
    SHOW_ALL, HIDE_PERSONAL_INFO,HIDE_ALL;
}

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
 /// .. more stuff

 package comds.domain;

  import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;


public abstract class COMDSEntity {

@GraphId
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || id == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    COMDSEntity entity = (COMDSEntity) o;

    if (!id.equals(entity.id)) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (id == null) ? -1 : id.hashCode();
}
}
```

And gradle build:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE")
 }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
     baseName = 'COM_DS'
version =  '0.1.0'
}

jar {
 baseName = 'COM_DS'
version =  '0.1.0'
```

}

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
 maven{ url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact"}
  maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/' }

}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.6.RELEASE")
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.5.1-SNAPSHOT"
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.5.0") 
   compile 'org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:1.0.1'
   compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j', version: '3.0.3'
   compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-core', version: '2.0.4'
   compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-api', version: '2.0.4'
   compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-http-driver', version: '2.0.4'
  compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver', version: '2.0.4'
  compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver', version: '2.0.4'

   compile group: 'com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog', name: 'jackson-jsog', version: '1.1'

   compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")

   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-facebook")
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
   compile "org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.1.4.RELEASE"
compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-security:1.1.4.RELEASE")
   compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-config:1.1.4.RELEASE")
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
   compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.4'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
   compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
   compile fileTree(dir: 'resources', include: ['*.jar'])
   providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
```

}

```
  task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
  }
```

Note Im a using a custom spring social linked in class, that is being imported in the last compile
Your help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I have the same issue, any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around solution. Instead of exporting to a war, I exported just a jar. The issue was that exporting the file as a war changed the file structure meaning the ogm mapping couldn't be done properly. My new gradle build looks like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.6.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
baseName = 'name'
version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
 maven{ url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact"}
  maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/'}
  maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'}


}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.6.RELEASE")
    compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.5.1-SNAPSHOT"
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.5.0") 
 compile 'org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:1.0.1'
 compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j', version: '3.0.3'
 compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-core', version: '2.0.4'
 compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-api', version: '2.0.4'
 compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-http-driver', version: '2.0.4'
 compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver', version: '2.0.4'
 compile group: 'org.neo4j', name: 'neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver', version: '2.0.4'
 compile group: 'org.pac4j', name: 'spring-webmvc-pac4j', version: '1.1.1'

 compile group: 'org.pac4j', name: 'pac4j-oauth', version: '1.9.2-SNAPSHOT'
 compile group: 'org.pac4j', name: 'pac4j-core', version: '1.9.2-SNAPSHOT'
 compile group: 'com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog', name: 'jackson-jsog', version: '1.1'

compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")


compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
compile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '8.5.4'
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '4.3.2.RELEASE'
compile fileTree(dir: 'resources', include: ['*.jar'])  

}

  task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
 gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```